# In Objective C: `if (A *a = castAsClassFn(A,something))` not working

Tags: objective-c

In a .h file I have:

```
@interface A : B <C> {
}
```

In a .mm file I have:

```
if (A *a = castAsClassFn(A,something)) { do stuff }
```

If I try to convert this to a .m file, it no longer compiles, with the error 'Unexpected interface name 'A':expected expression'. Is there anything I can do to make this work as a .m file?

Answer (score 1):

Objective-C doesn't support declaring a variable in an `if` statement expression. Just split the line:

```
A *a = castAsClassFn(A,something);
if (a) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I was told that it's fine as of c99. Thanks!